# apache web server 502 error proxy error when direct to an image url

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, redhat, proxypass, 502

Good day,

I have an Apache web server, and I configure ProxyPass it to my application server.

Everything is work unless the connection to the image in application server. I will hit 502 for the request to image url.

The following is my configuration in httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass "/myapp" "https://10.8.1.200/myapp"
ProxyPassReverse "/myapp" "https://10.8.1.200/myapp"
ProxyPass "/api" "https://10.8.1.200/api"
ProxyPassReverse "/api" "https://10.8.1.200/api"
ProxyPass "/image.web" "http://10.8.1.200/image.web" retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse "/image.web" "http://10.8.1.200/image.web"
```

The `/myapp` and `/api` will work perfectly, except the `/resource.web`.

As the full access of the url for `10.8.1.200` is accessible in `10.8.1.200` itself as follow:
`http://10.8.1.200/image.web/my.campaign.banner/promo.jpg`.

my apache version is :

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Red Hat)
```

Anyone know anything I miss out? or configure wrongly?

Comment: You're using https for everything except /image.web which is using http.

Comment: @yoonix, http is not allow?

Comment: Can't answer that with the information given.  You said all the others work, http/https is the obvious difference.